# python click, make option value optional

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-click

I am working on a small command line tool using [Python 2](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.12/python-2.7.12.msi) and [click](http://click.pocoo.org/6/). My tool either needs to write a value, read it, or do not change it. It would be nice if I could do the following:

`mytool --r0=0xffff`..........Set value `r0` to `0xffff`
`mytool --r0`......................Read value r0 
`mytool`...............................Don't do anything with `r0`

Based on the documentation, it doesn't seem possible, but I could have missed it. So is it possible or do I have to find a different approach?

Comment: `@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')`

Comment: @Koga Yeah, I had the same thought, but I was wondering if I could do something like that without using `default`

Comment: Why would you not want to use `default`?

Comment: @Koga The tool is to read/write register values in hardware. So if I give it a default value, the meaning would be `set register to a value of 1`. In other words calling just `mytool` would be equivalent to `mytool --r0=1`, which means `set register 0 to 1` which is not my intent.

Comment: Haven't worked with click, but could you use a non-integer default? What I'm not sure about is how to do nothing when it's not specified, but something when it's specified bare.

Comment: @mwchase That was another thought that I had. Right now I'm using `-2` to mean nothing, `-1` to mean read and `0` to `0xffffffff` to mean a write. But I think it is a bit ugly. Say I want to read `r0`. `mytool --r0` looks much better rather than `mytool --r0=-1`. It just doesn't look clean.

Comment: It would be problematic with an option that takes an 'optional' parameter. The syntax for the command line could easily end up being ambiguous, and it would not follow the Unix command line conventions.  @mwchase idea seems like a good solution. You could also maybe divide it up into two options, one boolean and one with the value. Or look at using commands instead.

Comment: Something that just occurred to me: what happens if you read from two registers? How do you format that? I don't know for sure, but maybe you should have a flag to read, that takes a register as an argument?

Answer (score 4):

Building on @Stephen Rauch's answer, I think I found a simpler solution

### Code

```py
class CommandWithOptionalFlagValues(click.Command):
    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        """ Translate any flag `--opt=value` as flag `--opt` with changed flag_value=value """
        # filter flags
        flags = [o for o in self.params if isinstance(o, click.Option) and o.is_flag and not isinstance(o.flag_value, bool)]
        prefixes = {p: o for o in flags for p in o.opts if p.startswith('--')}
        for i, flag in enumerate(args):
            flag = flag.split('=')
            if flag[0] in prefixes and len(flag) > 1:
                prefixes[flag[0]].flag_value = flag[1]
                args[i] = flag[0]

        return super(CommandWithOptionalFlagValues, self).parse_args(ctx, args)
```

### Test

```py
@click.command(cls=CommandWithOptionalFlagValues)
@click.option('--r0', is_flag=True, help='set or use default r0 value', flag_value=3.0)
@click.option('--r1', is_flag=True, help='Enable r1')
def cli(r0, r1):
    click.echo('r0: {} r1: {}'.format(r0, r1))

cli(['--r1'])
cli(['--r0', '--r1'])
cli(['--r0=5.0'])
```

### Result

```bash
r0: None r1: True
```

```bash
r0: 3.0 r1: True
```

```bash
r0: 5.0 r1: False
```

Comment: Great answer! There is a small error if @click.argument() parameters are present:

    AttributeError: 'Argument' object has no attribute 'is_flag'

Fixed by adding:

    options = [o for o in self.params if isinstance(o, click.Option)]

Fixed by adding:

Comment: @presto8  I edited the answer to add that check.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to introduce another parameter named `r0_set`.  And then to preserve the desired command line, we can inherit from `click.Command` and over ride `parse_args` to turn the user entered `r0=0xffff` into `r0_set=0xffff`

**Code:**

```
class RegisterReaderOption(click.Option):
    """ Mark this option as getting a _set option """
    register_reader = True

class RegisterWriterOption(click.Option):
    """ Fix the help for the _set suffix """
    def get_help_record(self, ctx):
        help = super(RegisterWriterOption, self).get_help_record(ctx)
        return (help[0].replace('_set ', '='),) + help[1:]

class RegisterWriterCommand(click.Command):
    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        """ Translate any opt= to opt_set= as needed """
        options = [o for o in ctx.command.params
                   if getattr(o, 'register_reader', None)]
        prefixes = {p for p in sum([o.opts for o in options], [])
                    if p.startswith('--')}
        for i, a in enumerate(args):
            a = a.split('=')
            if a[0] in prefixes and len(a) > 1:
                a[0] += '_set'
                args[i] = '='.join(a)

        return super(RegisterWriterCommand, self).parse_args(ctx, args)
```

**Test Code:**

```
@click.command(cls=RegisterWriterCommand)
@click.option('--r0', cls=RegisterReaderOption, is_flag=True,
              help='Read the r0 value')
@click.option('--r0_set', cls=RegisterWriterOption,
              help='Set the r0 value')
def cli(r0, r0_set):
    click.echo('r0: {}  r0_set: {}'.format(r0, r0_set))

cli(['--r0=0xfff', '--r0'])
cli(['--help'])
```

**Results:**

```
r0: True  r0_set: 0xfff
```

---

```
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --r0       Read the r0 value
  --r0=TEXT  Set the r0 value
  --help     Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: Isn't this solution rather complicated, given the use case?

Comment: @Te-jéRodgers, It is less than 20 lines of code.  There was a non-standard command line desired, so not sure how one goes about measuring complexity here.

Comment: Also, doesn't work as of today. Who knows what changed in Click, but the code above doesn't really make any difference in how Click's options behave.

Comment: Oh, I now realize that... it never actually worked. Well, the problem here is that I didn't even consider using `=`, but then reading the code I realized that this was essential. Also, I didn't use the long option names. Well. This is broken in far too many ways to be an actual solution.

Comment: @wvxvw, I just ran this code with click 8 and python 3.8 and got the exact same result as 4 years ago.  So I am very unclear what you are getting at here.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work as OP intended it to work. For instance, your code doesn't work if both short and long option names are used, it doesn't work subsequently if short option names are given together or separately, it doesn't work when space is used instead of equals. Basically, it doesn't work in *most* cases. It only works sometimes, perhaps, in the least likely way it will be used.

Comment: Finally, the help message is also wrong. It shouldn't list it as two separate options. It should be the same option with the default argument. I've researched this subject in Click's issue tracker, and inability to do this seems like a pain point that was mentioned to them multiple times, yet it doesn't seem to be solved. https://github.com/pallets/click/pull/1618 was supposed to solve it, instead, it seems to do some useless nonsense.