# How to add default argument to click option python

Tags: python, python-click

I'm working on a python CLI tool that uses click library.

I want to have an option `--opt1` that work as follows:

- If I run the program without that, its value should be `None`.
- If I run the program in this way `script --opt1`, its value should be the default value.
- If I provide a value for the option, I mean if I run the script in this way `script --opt1=value` its value should be `value`.

So I added the following option:

```
@click.option(
    "--opt1",
    metavar="PATH",
    default="opt1-default",
    type=click.Path(exists=True, resolve_path=True),
    show_default=True,
)
```

But when I'm running the command with option `--opt1` I'm getting the following error:

`Usage error: --opt1 option requires an argument` even though `--opt1 --help` shows the default value:

```
Options:
  --opt1 PATH    [default: opt1-default]
```

What could be the issue here?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're confusing options and flags. The default value is the value the program uses when you *don't* put `--opt1`. If you put `--opt1`, you need to give it a value.

Comment: Is there any way to give it default value? and if I don't specify this option don't assign any value at all?

Comment: So you want three states.  1) if --opt is not given, the value is None, 2) if --opt is given with no value, then use the default, 3) if --opt is used with a value, then the path must exist?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python click, make option value optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753999/python-click-make-option-value-optional)

Comment: Here is a GitHub discussion about your question. https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/549

Comment: @engmrgh yes, it does. Thanks.